# Paypal PDT error 4003

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, eclipse-pdt

After many hours of messing about and trying to set up what should be the relatively simple process of sending a payment to www.sandbox.paypal.com and being redirected back to a page on my site with a transaction id in the querystring, I have finally achieved it.

I am now receiving an error message 'FAIL Error 4003'.

Here is the code I am using. It is pretty much the same as the paypal example (all I have done is echo out the responses):

```
    <?php
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-synch';

$tx_token = $_GET['tx'];

$auth_token = "ZdoN6q4GLiRniR2BbOzEEF22GJOWHpVOXRtP7fAhBpvwwm5GyWcTzO_sSSO";
$req .= "&tx=$tx_token&at=$auth_token";

// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('www.paypal.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
// If possible, securely post back to paypal using HTTPS
// Your PHP server will need to be SSL enabled
// $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

if (!$fp) 
{
    // HTTP ERROR
    echo "HTTP Error";
} 
else 
{
    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
    // read the body data 
    $res = '';
    $headerdone = false;
    while (!feof($fp)) 
    {
        $line = fgets ($fp, 1024);
        if (strcmp($line, "\r\n") == 0) {
            // read the header
            $headerdone = true;
        }
        else if ($headerdone)
        {
            // header has been read. now read the contents
            $res .= $line;
            echo $line;
        }
    }

        // parse the data
        $lines = explode("\n", $res);
        $keyarray = array();
        if (strcmp ($lines[0], "SUCCESS") == 0) 
        {
            for ($i=1; $i<count($lines);$i++)
            {
                list($key,$val) = explode("=", $lines[$i]);
                $keyarray[urldecode($key)] = urldecode($val);
            }
            // check the payment_status is Completed
            // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
            // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
            // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
            // process payment
            $firstname = $keyarray['first_name'];
            $lastname = $keyarray['last_name'];
            $itemname = $keyarray['item_name'];
            $amount = $keyarray['payment_gross'];

            echo ("<p><h3>Thank you for your purchase!</h3></p>");
            echo ("<b>Payment Details</b><br>\n");
            echo ("<li>Name: $firstname $lastname</li>\n");
            echo ("<li>Item: $itemname</li>\n");
            echo ("<li>Amount: $amount</li>\n");
            echo ("");
        }
        else if (strcmp ($lines[0], "FAIL") == 0) {
            echo "Failure: " . $lines[0];
            // log for manual investigation
        }

}

fclose ($fp);

?>
<br />
Thank you for your payment. Your transaction has been completed, and a receipt for your purchase has been emailed to you. You may log into your account at <a href="http://www.sandbox.paypal.com/ie">www.sandbox.paypal.com/ie</a> to view details of this transaction.
```

I have made sure to confirm the email addresses for both my sandbox merchant and buyer accounts and enabled PDT.

The client is redirected correctly back to my 'thank you' page with the following querystring paramaters - `?tx=4FU63684496248523&st=Pending&amt=29.90&cc=EUR&cm=&item_number=`

Has anyone else encountered this error message? If so, what are the usual causes?

Comment: I actually called paypal about that error and they gave me a cryptic answer, saying that the error comes from some misconfiguration in my cart (i'm using ubercart). Not very helpful at all...

Comment: Here's another FAQ to throw into the mix: https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/13

Comment: I am using a simple form to submit the payment request to paypal and am actually using their own code to process the response. I have been developing web sites and applications for a fairly long time but have managed to steer clear of paypal for most of the time. I am astounded how bad their documentation, testing setup and general service is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that I was sending my test http request to paypal.com rather than sandbox.paypal.com. The answer was in the FAQ left by Jukebox.

> Check the script.When testing Payment Data Transfer (PDT) in the
>   Sandbox, make sure your PDT script POSTs back information to
>   www.sandbox.paypal.com. If testing on the Live PayPal site, make sure
>   the script POSTs data back to www.paypal.com. Currently, all sample
>   code on the Live and Sandbox sites "point" back to the live PayPal
>   site.

Hope it helps someone else get up and running quicker than I did. I am now onto my next issue which is the token being returned as empty rather than an error.. sigh..

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your transaction ID is not expired. 4003 PDT error code also comes when your transaction ID is expired.

Comment: Have you got any more information on when a transaction ID expires? Easy rep on this question as well if you have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23862124/paypal-pdt-transaction-id-expiration-period

Comment: how sure are you? AFAIK,PayPal transaction id never expires.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what solved it for me...

In the Buy Now button, I had a business email address associated with my LIVE PayPal account whereas I need to use the business email address associated with my SANDBOX PayPal account as in:

```
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="user@host.com">
```

The value attribute needed to reflect the business email address associated with my sandbox account.

By the way, here's an alternate PHP cURL version of the above script that also does the trick of eliciting a response from PayPal's sandbox:

```
if (isset($_GET['tx'])) {

$tx = $_GET['tx'];
$identity_token = "INSERT_YOUR_IDENTITY_TOKEN_HERE";

//echo $tx;

$url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';

$nvpString="cmd=_notify-synch".
           "&tx=$tx".
           "&at=$identity_token";

//echo $nvpString;

//define where the data is going to
$curl = curl_init($url);
//tell cURL to fail if an error occurs
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1); 
//allow for redirects
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
//assign the returned data to a variable
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
//set the timeout
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
//use POST
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
//set the POST data
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpString);
//execute the transaction
$response = curl_exec($curl);
//show errors
curl_error($curl);
//close the connection
curl_close($curl);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($response);
echo '</pre>';

}//end if (isset($_GET['tx']))
```

Answer (score 0):

The Identity Token of my test seller account changed without notification. Using the new (correct) Identity Token fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$tx=$_REQUEST['tx'];

$paypal_url='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-synch&tx='.$tx.'&at=token here';

$curl = curl_init($paypal_url);

$data = array(

"cmd" => "_notify-synch",

"tx" => $tx,

"at" => "token here"


);                                                                    

$data_string = json_encode($data); 

curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);

curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);

$headers = array (

'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',

'Host: www.paypal.com',

'Connection: close'

);

curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);

curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$response = curl_exec($curl);

$lines = explode("\n", $response);

$keyarray = array();

if (strcmp ($lines[0], "SUCCESS") == 0) {

for ($i=1; $i<count($lines);$i++){

list($key,$val) = explode("=", $lines[$i]);

$keyarray[urldecode($key)] = urldecode($val);

}


$first_name=$keyarray['first_name'];

$last_name=$keyarray['last_name'];

$payment_status=$keyarray['payment_status'];

$business=$keyarray['business'];

$payer_email=$keyarray['payer_email'];

$payment_gross=$keyarray['payment_gross'];

$mc_currency=$keyarray['mc_currency']; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some more information on Paypal’s PTD can be found here:
 http://www.secure-ebook.com/help/payment:paypal:fail_4003