# Paypal PDT transaction ID expiration period

Tags: php, paypal, transactions, paypal-pdt

I got error 4003 from paypal PDT when I was trying to retrieve payment information using the transaction ID. Although I there's a similar thread here : [Paypal PDT error 4003](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521800/paypal-pdt-error-4003)

and I believe the answer is because of my transaction ID has expired. However, I couldn't find any info of how long will the transaction ID expired.

p/s: My system is able to retrieve PDT info perfectly right after user return from paypal.